# Determine what is misdirecting a command line request to an already uninstalled application

Tags: macos

On my Mac I installed an application (Wine) using an installer. It installed the app into the Application folder. I needed to make a symbolic link to the Wine application in order for other tools to use it. But eventually I removed Wine.

Even though I removed it, if I open a terminal and type `wine`, the terminal gives me a message that it cannot find the file in the Applications folder:

> /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: No such file or directory

However, I need to install an updated version of wine that does not use an installer. I decided to place it in a different folder. Yet, no matter what I do, whenever I type `wine`, it always points to the Applications folder.

I even did a search for symbolic links and removed anything. But that didn't help. I checked my bash profile to make sure no path was pointing to the old version. Even if I update the bash profile to include a path to then new one, the old one still shows up in the terminal.

Getting rid of this old one is very frustrating and I have spent hours without success. Why is macOS still looking at the Applications folder?

Comment: Look in rou .bash_rc or .profile file in your directory.  Sometimes there are entries, alias’ or other references there that are not visible in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit more of a hassle than changing the environment variable, but you could do this:

1. Find the path of the wine application (If you just go to the app file itself, you can drag the file into the terminal window, and the path will be pasted in the terminal
2. Make a bash script that `cd`s into the application directory and run it, like this:

   ```
   cd ~/path/to/file/
   ./wine (or whatever the script is called)
   ```